# Qt QListWidget crash on selection state changed

Tags: c++, qt

I need to clear all the selected items of a QListWidgets, and then select a specific item, so i use this :

```
ui->lstGroupes->clearSelection();
ui->lstGroupes->item(0)->setSelected(true);
```

If i run theses two lines seperatly, they both work fine, but combines i get a crash (i'm running OS X Yosemite, btw). 
Is there a tweak to solve it ? The list is set to accept multiple selections, btw.

Comment: works for me on Linux and Qt 5.4, which version are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.4.1, downloaded like 5 days ago to be sure to have the latest version

Comment: do you get a NULL pointer from `ui->lstGroupes->item(0)`? You might want to get a debug version of Qt and debug it.

Comment: What do you mean by a null pointer ? i checked it seems like i get a proper item from the item() function

Comment: do you have any other slots connected to `lstGroupes`? Maybe the crash happens in code which you have not shown. What is the actual crash message you get?

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: I don't exactly get a crash message, i have the OS X "this application has crashed" window thing. I do not have others slots connected to this list, and basically nothing is doing anything to the list except for the slot you see on my code sample. This is really weird.

Comment: run the application with a debugger attached to get a more meaningful message.